# What is faster to execute, the same statement repeated or a looped statement?

Tags: performance, loops

What is faster to execute, the same statement repeated or a looped statement? Why?

**Repeated:**

```c
printf("Hello, world!\n");
printf("Hello, world!\n");
printf("Hello, world!\n");
printf("Hello, world!\n");
printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

**Looped:**

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

Where `printf("Hello, world!\n");` can be any piece of code.

I used C for the examples but my question is about all languages. Assume that the compiler/interpreter does not do any optimization.

Please reply about performance; not about readability, good practices, etc.

Comment: *"my question is about all languages. Assume that the compiler/interpreter does not do any optimization."* -- with these parameters, your question cannot be answered. Some language runtimes may display different execution speed and some may not, it completely depends on compiler optimizations, OS optimizations and/or runtime optimizations

Comment: It depends on the exact conditions. Usually, the non-loop will win. But, for example, if you see a compiled language, when the non-loop version is so big that it doesn't fit into cache, and the loop version fits, then the loop version can be faster.

Comment: Honestly, this reads like a homework dump. You just put down an assignment, even with instructions what you want and want not in the answers. What were **your** thoughts here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no optimization and naive compiler implementation of the loop, the unrolled version will always execute using fewer instructions. In fact, loop unrolling is a common compiler optimization.

To understand why, consider that the print statement will cost the same amount each time it's called. Let's use say that's one "operation". For the repeated call example, the cost is exactly 5 operations.

In the loop example, you'll have those same 5 print operations, but you also have the operations required to evaluate the loop condition and update the index variable. At the start, you have to assign the initial index value (1 operation), and at every iteration, you have to evaluate the condition (1 operation) and increment the index (1 operation). So your total operations in the looped case is

```
      1 initialization 
+ 5 * 2 condition & increment
+ 5 * 1 print 
--------------------------------
=    16 total operations
```

Big difference!

Now in reality, a print operation requires many more instructions than the loop bookkeeping, so the actual slowdown you see from using a loop is negligible. But for some loops, evaluating the body of the loop requires fewer instructions than computing the loop conditions, and you would see a dramatic difference in performance between a rolled and unrolled loop. A simple example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) sum += i;
```

Here, the body of the loop (`sum += i`) can be evaluated in a single `add` instruction on most architectures. This is the same number of instructions as incrementing the index variable `i`! So by writing it as a loop, we've doubled the execution time from 5 `add` instructions to 10 `add` instructions plus the instructions needed to evaluate the condition.

It is worth noting, however, that loop unrolling comes at the cost of increased code size. Larger binaries put more strain on the memory system, potentially resulting in slower execution. For repeated operations, your compiled binary has to include the code to compute that operation at every repeat. Let's say the `print` operation requires 20 instructions, and you're calling it 1000 times without looping. Your binary has to include 20000 instructions! But if you use a loop instead, you only need to output the instructions for the `print` operation once, plus some instructions for the loop evaluation (perhaps 10). So your binary only has 30 instructions in the looped case.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, the difference between using a loop statement that executes code N number of times or writing the same code N number of times without a loop is negligible. Using a loop may cause slightly worst performance, since it includes an iterator `i` incrementation and comparison, which are 2 additional CPU calculations.

Without the loop: `O(n)`.

With the loop: `O(3n)`.

(**Very** roughly)

Comment: I would say it is actually `O(3n)` since incrementing `i` and comparing to `5` are two separate procedures. And I'm not talking about how CPU runs this, which may be even worse.

Comment: @JordiVilaplana You are correct. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The printed statements are faster it will take time only to print 5 time but in loop time of increment,initialize  and condition checking will be included. But this time is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the repeated statement is faster because :
because in loop condition check and indexing also takes time so the number of statements are bigger and it takes more time to execute